# Custom List view adapter only showing 100 entries

Tags: android, parse-platform

I didn't use parse query adapter, instead I made a custom adapter and passed all the text and images in that but Parse only loads 100 items. Can anyone tell me how to get to the next page of the database without using the parse query adapter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a well known problem, the default limit is 100, you should use (saying that you have a `query` which is a `ParseQuery` object), you need to call the `query.setLimit(int N)` where  N represents the number of results that you want returned .